# Entity framework - populating child objects, filtering on a child of child

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, parent-child

I'm trying to optimize some code, but I'm having a bit of a problem with it. I have a database, and the tables in question look like this in the EDMX...
[image]

Each EmailQueue item can have multiple EmailContact and EmailEntity records, and each EmailContact could have multiple EmailSendFailures, though most will have none.

I want to get each EmailQueue where there is at least one EmailEntity record, and at least one EmailContact record that does not have an EmailSendFailure record. *EDIT: Also, I do not want to include those EmailContact records in this query. *

After some StackOverflowing and some trial and error, I was basically able to achieve something along these lines with this code:

```
var emails2 =
    (from eqs in
         this.context.EmailQueues
         .Include(q => q.EmailContacts)
         .Include(e => e.EmailEntities)
     where eqs.EmailContacts.Count > 0
     && eqs.EmailEntities.Count > 0
     && eqs.SentFlag == false
     select new
     {
         EmailQueue = eqs,
         EmailContact = eqs.EmailContacts.Where(c => !c.EmailSendFailures.Any()),
         EmailEntity = eqs.EmailEntities
     }).ToList();
```

The problem with that is it then returns a System.Collections.Generic.List<{EmailQueue:Tesa.DataModels.EmailQueue, EmailContact:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, EmailEntity:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable}>. I really don't want that. I want a List.

I tried this, which seems like it should work, but I get this error:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties.

```
List<EmailQueue> emails1 =
    this.context.EmailQueues.Include(q => q.EmailContacts.Where(c => !c.EmailSendFailures.Any()))
        .Include(e => e.EmailEntities)
        .Where(eqs => eqs.EmailContacts.Count > 0 && eqs.EmailEntities.Count > 0 && eqs.SentFlag == false)
        .ToList();
```

Anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong here? My suspicion is it's somewhere in the navigation properties, due to some of the problems I had during my "trial and error" (more error than trial) phase, prior to entering the "I give up, I'm posting to StackOverflow" phase.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing all the .includes first and then the where clause like:

```
context.Subjects.Include(r => r.RelatedSubjects).Include(t => t.Organisations).Include(y => y.Organisations.Select(i => i.Directories))
            .Where(y => y.Organisations.Any(e => e.Status == "Live")); }
```

Answer (score 0):

"I want to get each EmailQueue where there is at least one EmailEntity record, and at least one EmailContact record that does not have an EmailSendFailure record"

```
List<EmailQueue> result = context.EmailQueues.Where(e=>e.EmailEntities.Any() &&
e.EmailContacts.Any(ec=>!ec.EmailSendFailures.Any())).ToList();
```

Comment: I should have been more specific. Yes, that does satisfy my question as I wrote it. The problem is, I don't want to include any of the EmailContact records that do have an EmailSendFailure record. In my data, I have an EmailQueue record that has two EmailContact record, one of which has an EmailSendFailure record. This code returns both.

Comment: "This code returns both (EmailContact)", I don't understand, this query returns EmailQueue's not EmailContacts, this uses Lazy loading, if you navigate to the EmailContacts collection on each EmailQueue, Entity framework will perform a new call to the database and will retrieve the related EmailContacts